# Access variable from another php file's class function

Tags: php

I have two php files. one for class(Library), this class name() function returns variable, I want to access returned variable name to another php file. thank u.

**One.php**

```
<?php 
class One
{
  public function name()
  {
   $name = "SampleName";
   return $name;
  }
}
?>
```

**Two.php**

```
<?php
require_once("One.php");
$data = new One(); 
$data->name();

//$name = $this->name(); // I tried like this but not access
//echo $name;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the name from your example class:

```
echo $data->name();
```

You can't use variable `this`. You only can use `this` when you refer to the current object. But you are referring to the `one` object.

Comment: Thank You, it's right. and I am sorry to ask one more question, how can access returned array.

Comment: Glad i could help. If i answered your question please mark my answer as correct for other users with the same question/problem. If "name()" returns an array you can do this: $name = $data->name(); echo $name['phone'];